# How to get the values from the form to my php segment? My php segment does not recognize the submit button

Tags: php, html, web

I have a form which takes the data from users and send it to php but the issue is when submit button is clicked, the php segment does not recognizes it. What is the mistake I am doing? Any help would be appreciated.

I have written this code just check it..

```
 <form  action="dash.php" method="post" id="msform">

        <ul id="progressbar">
          <li class="active">About</li>
          <li>Details</li>
          <li>Submission</li>
        </ul>

        <fieldset class="first">
          <!-- <h2 class="fs-title">SignIn</h2> -->
          <h3 class="fsf-subtitle">About Blood-Camp</h3><br>
          <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Contact Email" required/>
          <input type="text" name="number" placeholder="Contact Number" required/>
          <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Contact Person Name" required/>
          <input type="button" name="next" class="next firstbutton action-button" value="Next" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="second">
          <!-- <h2 class="fs-title">Topic</h2> -->
          <h3 class="fsf-subtitle">Details about Blood-Camp</h3><br>
          <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" required/>
          <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address" required/>
          <input type="text" name="date" placeholder="Date" required/>
          <input type="text" name="time" placeholder="Timing" required/>

          <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
          <input type="submit" name="submit" class="next secondbutton action-button" value="Submit" />
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="third">
          <!-- <h2 class="fs-title">Topic</h2> -->
          <h3 class="fsf-subtitle">Thank You:)</h3><br><hr><br>
          <h4> Organization Name:-</h4><br>
          <h4> Contact No:-</h4><br>
          <h4> Email:-</h4><br>
          <h4> Address:-</h4><br>
          <h4> City:-</h4><br><hr><br>
            <h4>Your Blood Camp Details Will Be Updated And Everyone Will Get Notified Within 24 Hours Of Time.</h4><br><hr><br>
          <h4> Your Organization Is Creating a Deep Impact On Society :) </h4>


        </fieldset>


      </form>

    </section>

    </div>

    <script>

    var parent, next_fs, previous_fs;



    $(".next").click(function(){
      parent = $(this).parent();
      next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
      prev_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
      $(parent).hide();
      $(next_fs).show();
      $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(parent)).addClass("active");
       // $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(parent)).removeClass("active");

     });

     $(".previous").click(function(){
       parent = $(this).parent();
       prev_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
       $(parent).hide();
       $(prev_fs).show();
       // $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(prev_fs)).addClass("active");
       $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(prev_fs)).removeClass("active");

     });
     </script>
    </body>


    </html>

    <?php

        include('../dbcon.php');

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


           echo('divesh');
```

?>

I expect that atleast when submit is clicked, the php segment recognizes it

Comment: Is your PHP code in `dash.php`?

Comment: You are echoing after closing html tag. You won't see anything on page. You'd have to view page source to see that.

Comment: Yes, this code is in dash.php and even after echoing after closing html tag, nothing happens as such

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the form is in the dash.php page, move your php code in to the body of your html.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
       dash.php
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
    include('../dbcon.php');
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       echo('divesh');
       // print_r($_POST);
    }  
     ?>
    <form action="dash.php" method="post" id="msform">
      <!-- form fields and submit button -->
    </form>
  </body>
```

Comment: @diveshjain What happens? Blank screen?  Any error messages or anything in your php logs?

Comment: no error just the submit button "if" condition is itself not executed. Nothing is executed within the submit if condition. There is some issues in getting the data from html form i guess.